# How to remove or customize the pagination button in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'd like to remove the default button (or white dot) in Bootstrap carousel. 
Is it possible to customize them?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In terms of hiding, you can use CSS to make it hidden. For example,

```
.carousel-indicators li { visibility: hidden; }
```

would make all the dots be hidden.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to write your own template and add it by template-url param. E.g.:

```html
<div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
<a role="button" 
   href 
   class="left carousel-control" 
   ng-click="prev()" 
   ng-class="{ disabled: isPrevDisabled() }" 
   ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <span aria-hidden="true" 
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
</a>
<a role="button" 
   href 
   class="right carousel-control" 
   ng-click="next()" 
   ng-class="{ disabled: isNextDisabled() }" 
   ng-show="slides.length > 1">
    <span aria-hidden="true" 
          class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">next</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will think about this for future projects.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me

1. search for **.carousel-indicators li** in the css file bootstrap.min.css
2. change the *display* setting for the **carousel-indicators li** to *none*

example:

from this `.carousel-indicators li{display:inline-block;}`

to this   `.carousel-indicators li{display:none;}`

The dots will no longer be displayed.

Comment: Do not change **bootstrap.min.css** file. ( its not a good programming skill ) Just make your own **style.css** file and write these line of code in that.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `indicators` part from carousel declaration:

```html
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) prevent from switching

```
$('.carousel-indicators li').each(function(){
    $(this).carousel('pause');
});
```

2) remove the active class..

```
$('.carousel-indicators .active').removeClass('active')
```

Comment: but this is JavaScript... can I remove it without JavaScript?

Comment: bootstrap uses jquery... I don't know how you would disable it without using js

Answer (score 0):

Write below mentioned CSS code to hide prev/next indicator for bootstrap 4.5

```
.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon{
  display:none;
}
```

or

```
.carousel-control-next-icon, .carousel-control-prev-icon{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Below is the CSS code to hide indicator

```
 .carousel-indicators li
{
  display: none;
}
```